# Opening Excel through Process.Start doesn't allow an Excel add-in to load

Tags: c#, excel, security, excel-addins

I created a C# plugin (for a database program) that launches Excel using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start.

When Excel opens that way, one Excel add-in which is set to load at startup doesn't launch while others do.

When I open Excel manually (not running it as administrator), all add-ins launch.

I imagine it is a permission or security issue? I tried running the database program as admin and it didn't make a difference.

Why is launching Excel through Process.Start different from launching Excel manually? Is there a way I can solve this problem from within my plugin?

Comment: Keep trying...you'll get there.  Let us know how you went

Answer (score 0):

Does this link give you any information?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/haahmadi/2010/05/26/my-office-addin-does-not-load/

Specifically step 3.

> Set the "VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS" environment variable to 0. Then
>   go back to the registry key I mentioned in step 1 and set the
>   LoadBehavior to 3. Now restart the Excel. You should be able to see a
>   dialog describing what is happening:

The registry key they are talking about is here
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins